# How to ignore the warnings in R tryCatch in do parallel loop

Tags: r, foreach, try-catch, warnings, doparallel

I am building a Arima model in R. I am trying to use tryCatch to handle exceptions in the model training--particularly in scenarios where I do not have enough data to build the model. As I have so many models trained (around 380), I tried to implement this using doParallel package in R. 
But I noticed that there are warnings which I simply need to ignore. Given below is what I have tried. But I can see some threads are just stuck. I am just wondering whether the warning handling code is putting the threads in an infinite loop because I try to call the same expression inside the warnings.

```
        #some sample data
ops <- ['Android', 'iOS']
country <- ['US', 'CA']
apps <- ['A', 'B', 'C']


nCores <- detectCores()
registerDoParallel(cores = nCores)

foreach(os=ops)%:% foreach(country=countries) %:% foreach(app=apps)%dopar%{ 
modeling <- function(y_data) 
{
#the function model is implemented inside the models.R #source file
#it basically uses auto.arima with some fourier regressors 
#and returns to model

source("models.R")

#for each condition get data as y_data
tryCatch( 
{ 
suppressWarnings ( 
out <- model(data=y_data)
) 
}, 

warning=function(w)
{ 
print(w) 
suppressWarnings ( 
out <- model(data=y_data) 
) 
},
error=function(e) {
print(e) 
return(NULL) }

write.table(out$AICC, "results.csv")
}


modeling(y_data)
}
```

Note that first I tried it with just 4 loop iterations, and the first one ran quite fast, but the other 3 iterations are running forever.

Comment: Why are you loading the source for models.r within your loop instead of doing so prior to the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to ignore the warnings but print a warning in `suppressWarning`?

```
...
warning=function(w)
{ 
print(w) 
suppressWarnings ( 
...
```

You don't provide a reproducible example but I would try to start with a minimal set of lines:

```
...
nCores <- detectCores()
registerDoParallel(cores = nCores)
source("models.R")

modeling <- function(y_data) {
  tryCatch({
    suppressWarnings(out <- model(data=y_data))
    })
}

foreach(os=ops) %:% foreach(country=countries) %:% foreach(app=apps) %dopar% {
  modeling(y_data)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful suggestion. Parallelized model works. However but the first iteration completes much faster, within 8 minutes, while the rest of the iterations take much longer, even though the number of data points in each iteration is not that different. Any idea on what could be the reason? (using 4 cores, and tested with just 4 iterations)

Comment: If you provide a reproducible example... But I think, this is a new question.